# How to test inserting a has_many relation with spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm inserting a User in a Page (a page has many users through memberships table), and I'm expecting it to fail since a Role is required. I have validate_presence_of on user, page and role on the membership (join table).

My issue is that the test breaks before it reaches the end, because an exception is thrown. So I thought, I'll add an 'expect raise' to it

```
it 'should not be valid without a role' do
  user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
  expect { page.users << user }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
end
```

But this doesn't really test, that the error was caused by the lack of Role (Validation error: No Role provided). Is there a better way to test this? Or is there a way to set the user in the page.users without saving it, and then check if page is valid?

Update:

This does not work either (exception is thrown on page.users << users, invalid active record, role must be provided):

```
it 'should not be valid without a role' do
  user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
  page.users << user
  page.should have(1).error_on :role
end
```

Update 2:

I think I have the answer, this works for now

```
it 'should not be valid without a role' do
  user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
  expect { page.users << user }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, /Role must be provided/)
end
```

Comment: please show us what `page` is also

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem.

You also can try using the syntax:

```
it { should have(1).error_on :role }
```

Basically you have access to the errors from your spec and can check that there is one on the field you want to have one.

Comment: I've done that and added a validate_uniqueness_of, but because I inject a user directly in the pages and saving it (page.users << user) it throws a validation error, before it reaches the validation check of shoulda.

Comment: It never reaches that line, because page.users << user throws an ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Valdation failed: Role must be provided exception.

Comment: There is nothing special on the model:

  validates_presence_of :user, :role, :page
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:page_id], message: "already has rights to this page"